Replace characters in text file faster
I have a text file (approximately 1.7GB). I open it, read it into a string, replace various characters, write the string back to the text file and close it.
How can I make this working code faster?
Function RemoveCharactersFromText(sFile as string) as string

Dim sText as String
dim sLineContect as String
Dim iFileNum as Integer

Open sFile for Input as iFileNum

Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
     Line Input #iFileNaum, sLineContent
     sText = sText & sLineContent & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum

On Error Resume Next
sText = Replace(sText, ",", "")
sText = Replace(sText, "#", "")
sText = Replace(sText, "*", "")
sText = Replace(sText, "+", "")
sText = Replace(sText, "=", "")
sText = Replace(sText, Chr(34), "")
sText = Replace(sText, "null", "")
On Error GoTo 0

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFile for Output as iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sText
Close iFileNum

iFileNum = 0

I tried writing the entire text file to the string in one hit:
Open sFile for Input as FreeFile
sText = Input(EOF(iFileNum), iFileNum)

I also tried via FSO:
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     sText = .OpenTextFile(sFile, 1).ReadAll
End With

I get errors with both of these.

Create a tool on .NET VB.

Your code does nothing. It reads the file line by line into sTemp, then ignores it and uses sText which is empty. It's not clear why you would want to build the entire string to begin with, as you can do replacement line by line. Which is the right thing to do with a 1.7 GB file, because after you read it in this way, it would be a 3.4 GB string, except that you cannot have a string that large.

You should avoid replace by single character multiple times. Those would allocate again and again. Consider use intermediate and small buffer and flush it when encountered unexpected character.

The UNIX program sed is great for things like this (also the command cut can be used if it's only for removal of characters). In case you're working with a Windows computer, you might consider installing a Cygwin for this.

What error do the code pieces extracting the file content at once, raise? Do you try it in Windows? All that besides the typo (strTemp instead of sText)...

My original post worked on 189MB but I could not read a 185 GB file using a buffer. This code processed the file in 121 seconds. Thanks GSerg.

Sub Test2()
    Const SourceFilePath As String = "D:\Test.txt"
    Const DestFilePath As String = "D:\Test_Output.txt"
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer
    ' Process the file
    RemoveTextInFileByReplace SourceFilePath, DestFilePath
    
    ' Replace the original file with the processed file
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill DestFilePath ' Delete the original source file
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub

Sub RemoveTextInFileByReplace(ByVal SourceFilePath As String, ByVal DestFilePath As String)
    Dim SourceFile As Integer, DestFile As Integer
    Dim FileLine As String
    
    ' Open the source file for reading
    SourceFile = FreeFile
    Open SourceFilePath For Input As #SourceFile
    
    ' Open the destination file for writing
    DestFile = FreeFile
    Open DestFilePath For Output As #DestFile
    
    ' Read the file line by line
    Do While Not EOF(SourceFile)
        Line Input #SourceFile, FileLine
        FileLine = Replace(FileLine, ",", "")
        FileLine = Replace(FileLine, "#", "")
        FileLine = Replace(FileLine, "*", "")
        FileLine = Replace(FileLine, "+", "")
        FileLine = Replace(FileLine, "=", "")
        FileLine = Replace(FileLine, Chr(34), "")
        FileLine = Replace(FileLine, "null", "")
        Print #DestFile, FileLine ' Write the modified line to the destination file
    Loop
    
    ' Close the files
    Close #SourceFile
    Close #DestFile
End Sub


The "null" may end up spanning two buffers, and will not get replaced. The recreation of the regex for each line is also a questionable solution.

@GSerg I updated my answer to process the file twice doubling the buffer size on the second pass.  It processed a 189MB text file in ~11 seconds, which seems reasonable.   What do you think?

I think it's an overkill :) And it doesn't seem like it's required to re-process the single-character replacements, they are guaranteed to be replaced on the first pass. Unless it's known that the file is a single huge line, it's probably easier to do Line Input like the OP does. Just without concatenating it all.

@GSerg The reason that I wanted to use  RegEx is that I know that it is much much faster at large text replacement.  That being said, I was unable to read a 189 GB using the buffer approach.  I updated my code  reading line by line.  Thanks again
